# markers on angular google map cause infinite digest loop

Tags: angularjs, digest, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to create a google map with markers on it, in an angular js front end.
I can create the map, and can add markers. But when I add the markers, my console fills up with infinite digest errors.

I'm using the [angular google maps project](http://angular-google-maps.org/api#markers)

[This is the error I get](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3a%20function%20%28%29%7Bvar%20a=l%28e%29;p%28a,J%5Bc%5D%29%7C%7C%28p%28a,m%29?n%28e,a=J%5Bc%5D%29%3aJ%5Bc%5D=a%29;return%20m=a%7D;%20newVal)

### My template code

```
<google-map draggable="true" doCluster="true" center="map_settings.centre" zoom="map_settings.zoom" id="google_map">
    <markers models="map_marker_models()" coords="'self'" icon="">
</markers>
</google-map>
```

### *relevant* controller code

```
$scope.map_marker_models = function() {
    var jao = [];
    for (var c_result = 0; c_result < $scope.results.length; c_result++){
        jao[c_result] = {
            "latitude": $scope.results[c_result].a, 
            "longitude": $scope.results[c_result].o
        };
    }
    return jao;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exception being thrown (including stacktrace) in the console?  I dont believe you have given us enough to help you.

Comment: @Nix thanks very much for your offer of help, I've since switched out to this angular google maps project (https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) instead and so the exception is long gone...
The previous angular project looks fantastic, just wish it had some working examples to reference..

Comment: Please delete then...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, what helped me was switching to the latest version of Angular. I think this seems to be an issue with version 1.0 of Angular working along side of the Google Maps API. Try with 1.2 and you should not see any issues.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that when back in the project and report back

Comment: Updating from Angular 1.2 to 1.2.15 fixed the problem for me.  @sam, any chance of you accepting Chris' answer?